# Once we've constructed N, do we need again the axiom of infinity to conclude the set of the primes is infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, infinity, axioms

When completing the proof (unfortunately, at the same time presenting it as Euclid's and performing it *ad absurdum*) of the infinitude of prime numbers, my algebra professor stated "...and thus the set of the primes is *not finite*. By the axiom of infinity, we conclude it is *infinite*. "

But obviously such a set is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and this exists exactly thanks to the axiom of infinity. So why isn't this axiom implicit in the proof? That is, why isn't the last sentence redundant?

Comment: You need the axiom of infinity to construct $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @GitGud That's what "and this exists exactly thanks to the axiom of infinity" stands for. Note that I am concerned about the need of the axiom in the proof, not in general.

Comment: @GitGud: I've made some clarifications.

Comment: You can't talk about primes or natural numbers without the axiom of infinity, without it, the statements you speak of don't even have meaning.

Comment: @GitGud: Read the edited title, please.

Comment: Now this is different.

Comment: @GitGud: I'm sorry if I had failed to make it clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can easily prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers without appealing to the axiom of infinity. The usual proof by Euclid does just that.

The axiom of infinity is used to show that the collection of natural numbers is a set, and therefore the collection of prime numbers is a set as well.

Comment: As I thought... thank you. The "funny" thing is that my professor thoroughly explained that we only derived the "non finiteness" of the set, and the axiom was needed in order to conclude it was infinite. Which makes sort of no sense as, again, the axiom is already there. Meh.

Comment: Yes, it seems a dubious nicety. Clearly they have already constructed the integers, and so have assumed AxInfinity. Without that, as you point out, you can't form the set of all primes in order to ask what its size is. If "finite" is defined as "is bijectible with an integer", and "infinite" defined as "not finite" in that sense, then Euclid's proof shows that the collection of primes is infinite.

Comment: @BrianO: Indeed. Well, thank you too, Brian. :)